# Android N Intent Extras is null when i put them in push notification gcm listener

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android

I am working with push notifications in Android N.

I put extras in pending intent:

```
intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);

            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, GenerateId(), intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .SetSmallIcon(context.ApplicationInfo.Icon)
                    .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
                    .SetContentTitle(title)
                    .SetContentText(message)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent); 
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

            var notification = notificationBuilder.Build();
            var id = GenerateId();
            notificationManager.Notify(id, notification);
```

Then i need to get extras

```
protected override void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();
    var message = Intent.Extras.GetInt(MessageKey);
}
```

In this case Extras is null

The second question is how to identify when 4 notifications are grouped?

Answer (score 0):

When `MainActivity` gets created, you need to determine if it was started from a notification pending intent vs. started as the main app launcher, etc... You can perform null checks in `this.Intent?` and `this.Intent.Extra?`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    var message = Intent?.Extras?.GetInt("MessageKey");
    if (message != null)
    {
        Log.Debug("SO", message.ToString());
        // activity started from notification, do something with message id...
    }
    ~~~~~
}
```

Comment: Its clear. I check the data in this way: !Intent.Extras.IsNull() && Intent.Extras.ContainsKey("MessageKey"). But my issue is Extras==null in Android N (Google Pixel). In other devices I can get extras from intent.

Comment: @DimaBabich You are using `NotificationCompat`, which `Activity` class  are you subclassing?

Comment: In 2 days I have to update my question. I do not have extras when I tap on grouped notifications. 
My activity is Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity